# Can I data cache an IQueryable<> collection?

Tags: linq-to-sql

can this be cached?

Answer (score 3):

No, you would need to enumerate it (e.g. using ToList()) and cache the results of the enumeration.  Caching the IQueryable object itself is effectively just caching the query: in that scenario it will still be re-executed every time you try to use the results.